# How to get back iMovie version compatible with macOS 10.14?

Tags: mojave, restore, imovie

How can I get an iMovie version compatible with macOS 10.14. I deleted it to clear up space on the hard drive, but I need it now and the App Store only lists a version compatible with 10.15+

Apple Support recommended to reinstall Mojave (or upgrade) which I would like to avoid. What are my other options to get a compatible iMovie version?

Comment: I assume Apple Support already has ruled out the option of accessing iMovie in your Purchase history? Reinstalling macOS to get it back may sound strange but seems to be doable. What are your concerns about it?

Comment: Presumably you don't have a backup?

Comment: Do you have a friend with a Mac with the "correct" version of macOS? Oddly enough most apps *can* be copied from one Mac to another. So that might be something to consider.

Comment: @SteveChabers I tried this with an older version, but it didn't up working. Unfortunately I'm running an old version and don't have a db which maps iMovie version to name, but I wish I did :p

Answer (score 2):

If you attempt to install iMovie from the “Purchased” tab of the Mac App Store, you will be given the option to install the last compatible version. This must be done from the Purchased tab, and not anywhere else on the Mac App Store, or the dialog will not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still remember the exact version of iMovie running on your Mac? Try to google the download link if so. [This page](https://www.movieforwindows.com/imovie/download-an-older-version-of-imovie.html) includes links to some old versions of iMovie. Maybe you could try iMovie 10.1.10 or 10.1.12 on your macOS 10.14.